# Excel: Color Code Subset of Pie Charts

Tags: excel, charts, pie-chart

[image: Sample Pic]

Hello, I was wondering if it is possible to color code groups of the pie chart together, but not manually do it slice by slice. For example, Apartments would be grouped together as light blue, and then Self Storage as dark blue. The pieces would retain their original percentage still though. This would make it easier to identify groups of data more easily. Any input?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any input? Well, first, don't use pie charts for charts with more than two or three data points. They are hard to interpret. Use horizontal bar charts instead.

The data seems to be sorted by value. If you want to group by category, you will need to sort by category, too.

Excel will automatically apply a different color to each pie chart wedge. You can manually change these colors. You can use VBA to automate that.

A horizontal bar chart will give you a lot more tools to visualize the data and turn it into information.

[image]